# Retrieve Video URL from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook's Graph API to retrieve videos from a page. These are then displayed using the source field.

However, the source urls go bad from time to time. Here for instance is one that once worked:

https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xft1/v/t42.1790-2/12050042_768647579925312_779118818_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjgxMSwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic2QifQ%3D%3D&rl=811&vabr=451&oh=4daf51daafbbe22d93d5379fe422fce5&oe=560BF031

Then it stopped working. Running the API again this is the correct URL now:

https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xft1/v/t42.1790-2/12050042_768647579925312_779118818_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjgxMSwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic2QifQ%3D%3D&rl=811&vabr=451&oh=3f966aea5cc0917dcad2448e01aa03f1&oe=560DEA71

Anyone know what the issue is here? I must be able to get a reliable version of that URL.

Comment: Those are Facebook's CDN URLs. They are not guaranteed to not expire.